# what are "transaction fees" used for?

Tags: transaction-fees

if I set a transaction fee from multibit for example, is it a fee I'm paying or is it a fee that the other party is paying; and to whom does that fee go to?

Answer (score 3):

The fee goes to the miners and is deducted from your wallet.  Including a fee in your transaction improves the chance that your transaction will quickly be included in a block.

Answer (score 3):

[wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction_fees)

> The transaction fee is an incentive on the part of the bitcoin user to make sure that a particular transaction will get included into the next block which is generated.